# understanding the meaning of a particular TypeScript index signature

Tags: typescript

I was looking at a `Diff` method provided by Anders Hejlsberg in this github thread: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-307871458

I don't quite understand the meaning of this index signature `{ [x: string]: never }` in the context of the type

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
```

he explains

> it relies on the fact that an object with a string index signature can be indexed with any string.

but it's still not clicking for me

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which part? `[x: string]` or `never`?

Comment: That is a very old trick to filter string literal types. These days conditional types and specifically the predefined `Exclude` conditional type do the same thing but better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: Do not use `Diff` in typescript today. Since typescript 2.8 we have had a better alternative to diff built-into the default types called `Exclude`. `Exclude` uses conditional types to filter types much cleaner.

`Diff` used to be a trick to filter string literal types. The trick uses two peculiar properties of `never`

- `T & never` is `never`
- `T | never` is `T`

The first mapped type `{[P in T]: P }` produces a type that has the value for each key the same as the key name. So if `T` is `'a' | 'b'` this mapped type produces `{a : "a", b: "b"}`

The second mapped type produces a type with `never` for those keys we want to remove. So if `U` is `'b'` this mapped type produces `{ b: never }`

Intersecting those two produces `{a : "a", b: "b"} & { b: never }` which is `{a : "a", b: "b" & never }` which reduces to `{a : "a", b: never }`.

If we were to get a union of the values of the above type (ie `(... & ...)[T]`), we would get our `Diff` result, since `({a : "a", b: never })["a" | "b"]` would be `"a" | never` so `"a"`

But this is where we have a problem. Back in typescript 2.4, if we were to index by `T`, we would get an error (this `type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never })[T];` this is an error [see playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.4.1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgMwQHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcpDgAnOXAcwBooBVDbPIk8yqgPigF4oAKAN4BtAApRKUVAF0AXFHEBfKADIoI8ZPpyouCADcIZKIoCUwmQG4oAKCA)) Because typescript was not satisfied that the previously defined intersection was indexable by `T`. This is actually no longer an issue in current typescript ([see](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgMwQHgCpQgD2BAdgEwGcpDgAnOXAcwBooBVDbPIk8yqgPigF4oAKAN4BtAApRKUVAF0AXFHEBfKADIoI8ZPpyouCADcIZKIoCUwmQG4oAKCA)). But at the time this trick was useful, we needed something extra to convince the compiler to allow indexing by `T`.

This something extra was `{ [x: string]: never }`. It would allow indexing by any string (so `[T]` would work). And it would not impact the result of the indexing operation, as any other key values would be in the union with this `never` from the index, and `never` in a union just melts away.

Comment: thank you for itching that scratch for me - even though it's not a problem anymore I still had to know :)

Comment: @Jordan Always fun to explain complex types, maybe we should start a type history page, with old type hacks 

Comment: I just started deep diving into TS so this is the first type hack I know of (actually I may have one related to destructuring), but I can propose a new wiki page for this in the TS github repo. Do you know if this was specific to any `type` intersection involving a property with value `never`?